# How to Change Path of a Multi-Dimensional Array Using CakePHP Core Utility - Set

Tags: arrays, cakephp, set

How do I use Cakephp core utility - "Set" to change the format of this multi-dimensional array:

```
array(
  [Product]
     [offer_id]
         [0] => '1'
         [1] => '5'
)
```

to

```
array(
  [Product]
     [0]
         [offer_id] => '1'
     [1]
         [offer_id] => '5'
)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SET is not required and actually may be more cumbersome than what is required for this operation. Try using something like:

```
$test = array_values($array['Product']['offer_id']);
foreach($test as $value) {
    $products['Product'][]['offer_id'] = $value;
}
// show the array
pr($products);
```

This will accomplish what you are trying to do.